# NPE Null Pointer Exception in Yabe

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, playframework

I'm working through the Yabe tutorial and have run into some Null Pointer Exception in the test useTheCommentsRelation

```
useTheCommentsRelation

A java.lang.NullPointerException has been caught, null
In /test/BasicTest.java, line 96 :

 bobPost.addComment("Jeff", "Nice post"); 
 Hide tracejava.lang.NullPointerException
at models.Post.addComment(Post.java:30)
at BasicTest.useTheCommentsRelation(BasicTest.java:96)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Here is the test code;

```
@Test
public void useTheCommentsRelation() {
    // Create a new user and save it
    User bob = new User("bob@gmail.com", "secret", "Bob").save();

    // Create a new post
    Post bobPost = new Post(bob, "My first post", "Hello world").save();

    // Post a first comment
    bobPost.addComment("Jeff", "Nice post");
    bobPost.addComment("Tom", "I knew that !");

    // Count things
    assertEquals(1, User.count());
    assertEquals(1, Post.count());
    assertEquals(0, Comment.count()); // 2 when correct not 0

    // Retrieve Bob's post
    bobPost = Post.find("byAuthor", bob).first();
    assertNotNull(bobPost);

    // Navigate to comments
    assertEquals(2, bobPost.comments.size()); 
    assertEquals("Jeff", bobPost.comments.get(0).author);

    // Delete the post
    bobPost.delete();

    // Check that all comments have been deleted
    assertEquals(1, User.count());
    assertEquals(0, Post.count());
    assertEquals(0, Comment.count());
}
```

and here is the Post class with the addComment method near the end.

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
public class Post extends Model{

public String title;
public Date postedAt;

@Lob
public String content;

@ManyToOne
public User author;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="post", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Comment> comments;  
public Post(User author, String title, String content){
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
    this.postedAt = new Date();
}
public Post addComment(String author, String content) {
    Comment newComment = new Comment(this, author, content).save();
    this.comments.add(newComment);
    this.save();
    return this;
}
}
```

The Comment Class

```
package models;

import java.util.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import play.db.jpa.*;

@Entity
public class Comment extends Model{
public String author;
public Date postedAt;
@Lob
public String content;
@ManyToOne
public Post post;
public Comment(Post post, String author, String content){
    this.post = post;
    this.author = author;
    this.content = content;
    this.postedAt = new Date();
}
}
```

Thanks to everyone who has gotten me this far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer of sorts,  A complete correct version of Yabe is included in the install in
`play_installation] samples-and-tests`
If you ever get too confused you can compare and contrast to see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see that Post.comments is initialized anywhere, but addComment() tries to dereference it with `this.comments.add(...)`.

Comment: Comments is it's own class.  I added the code in the decription.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with that. In your Post class, you have a field named comments: `public List<Comment> comments;`. In addComment(), you say `this.comments.add(newComment);`. But nowhere is there a `comments = new ...`. Thus in addComment(), `this.comments` is null and hence the NPE.

Comment: I'm getting that the list class cannot be instantiated.   I'm hoping it's poor syntax.

    
The file /app/models/Post.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : Cannot instantiate the type List<Comment>


In /app/models/Post.java (around line 30)

26:   this.content = content;

 27:   this.postedAt = new Date();

 28:  }

 29:  public Post addComment(String author, String content) {

 30:   List<Comment> comments = new List<Comment>();

 31:   Comment newComment = new Comment(this, author, content).save();

 32:   this.comments.add(newComment);

 33:   this.save();

 34:   return this;

Comment: It would be nice if you could put code format into the comments.

Comment: [List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface. You need an implementation like [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [LinkedList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Comment: Changing it to ArrayList through a new error...  `JPA error 

A JPA error occurred (Unable to build EntityManagerFactory): Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: models.Post.comments
`

Comment: Your property should read `private List<Comment> comment = new ArrayList<Comment>();`

Answer (score 0):

I know you kind of answered yourself by providing the generic tip to go and look for the samples code in your Play! installation, but for somebody else getting here this might be more helpful:

@RyanStewart is right, you need to initialize "Post.comments".

It actually *is* written in the tutorial, but it's really easy to miss it (I did it myself, and I'm too used to Django niceness to do everything myself to realize I might have to initialize this myself!)

```
public Post(User author, String title, String content) {
...
    this.comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
...
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I did the test at home, slight difference between the original answer and the new one:

- I did not notice the List in your code, as it's too close to the constructor. My bad!
- I forgot to add the refresh method to retrieve the new state from the database on the entity

Modify the method:

```
public Post addComment(String author, String content) {
    Comment newComment = new Comment(this, author, content).save(); //adds the comment
    return this.refresh(); //tell Hibernate to get the latest state from the DB
}
```

This will save the comment properly. Test code:

```
@Test
    public void useTheCommentsRelation() {
        // Create a new user and save it
        UserT bob = new UserT("bob@gmail.com", "secret", "Bob").save();

        // Create a new post
        Post bobPost = new Post(bob, "My first post", "Hello world").save();

        // Post a first comment
        bobPost.addComment("Jeff", "Nice post");
        bobPost.addComment("Tom", "I knew that !");

        // Count things
        assertEquals(1, UserT.count());
        assertEquals(1, Post.count());
        assertEquals(2, Comment.count()); // 2 when correct not 0
        assertEquals(2, bobPost.comments.size());

    }
```

The rest of the code is the same as you show in your question. The test passes for me. NOTE: if you run it twice in a row and you are not wiping the DB between tests, it will fail in the asserts.

Alternatively you can use these changes to Post:

```
public Post(UserT author, String title, String content) {
    this.author = author;
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
    this.postedAt = new Date();
    this.comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
}

public Post addComment(String author, String content) {
    Comment newComment = new Comment(this, author, content).save();
    this.comments.add(newComment);
    return this.save();
}
```

This will work without need to reread from the database the state, as it is updated immediately. This also passes the test.

Comment: All of that is present. Still cannot instantiate a list

comments = new List<Comment>();

Comment: No, the add comment method is not the same. You don't have to instantiate comments with new List, this will be managed by hibernate once you start adding comments. Please try the addComment method I added.

Comment: What you're suggesting is to break the object model by assuming it will be loaded by Hibernate before being used.

Comment: You never add the new Comment to the comments collection. This should work, and with your solution, it wouldn't: `post.addComment("foo", "bar"); assert post.getComments().size() == 1;` In fact, that would also fail with an NPE. This is a bad "fix" for this kind of problem. I've seen it attempted many times before, and it always leads to problems.

Comment: New day, new read from the basic test;

`A javax.persistence.PersistenceException has been caught, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
In /test/BasicTest.java, line 113 :

 bobPost.delete(); `

Comment: Hey Ryan, Pere, Thanks for your answers.  I was starting to do yabe from the beginning, when it reminded me that a complete correct version is available in the sample directory.  I wasn't properly initializing my comments list as you said.